# I have solved the 1st of three phases of a panhellenic competition (it is now over)

Tags: c++, code-complexity

I have solved the 1st of three phases of a panhellenic competition (it is now over) but i am interested in knowing whether there is any simpler complexity algorithm or not
7 9

5 7

4 2

3 6

2 3

1 7

6 2

4 6

1 5

3 4

```
int main()    
{    
    ifstream in("domes.in");    
    ofstream out("domes.out");    

    int orio,z;
    in>>orio;  
    in>>z;    
    int domes[orio];    

    for(int i=0;i<orio;i++){domes[i]=0;}
    int k;  
    for(int i=0;i<2*z;i++)  
    {
        in>>k;
        domes[k-1]++;
    }  

    int c=0;  

    for(int i=0;i<orio;i++)  
    {  
        if(domes[i]<2)
            c++;
    }  
    out<<c;
    return 0;
}
```

it is about some places(represented by numbers)the first two numbers are number of places (orio) and the number of matches (z). The places are "connected" somehow (meaningless). You should find how many places have less than 2 connections and the output (c in this case) is the number of the places that have less than 2 connections. k is a variable used temporarily to insert each number and plusplus the times it is "seen" . If it is seen it means that it is connected to another place. I don't think there is a simpler solution, but some of my peer's programs needed less time to run and that troubled me

Comment: Yay! You did it! Gratz!

Comment: That's cool! I guess [a silly Wikipedia is slightly misleading here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panhellenic_Games). Could you explain more clearly how algorithm supposed to work?  didn't get it.

Comment: xD yes i suppose!It is quite simple.Each city lets say,numbered from 1 to "orio"(the first number) connects with another.The number of connections is "z"(the second number).You are supposed to find and print how many cities are not connected with at least two others. When i read the input file i "save" temporarily the number into k.Then I do domes[k-1]++;. Why k-1 and not just k?because the array is starting from zero and the cities form 1.I do +1 that place of the array because i have "seen" that the city is connected with another. Then scan the array to see which connects with less than 2

Comment: What's the question exactly?  Are you concerned about how 'slow' your algorithm was compared to your peers' code?  How much slower is your code than their code?

Comment: Yes that is the question 0,004 seconds :P its just a bit but i wonder why...  P.S. please vote-up @Ryan !!  I need some reputation in order to answer or vote-up questions :p

Comment: Is the 0,004 an average?  4 milliseconds isn't a lot of time.  If you took the measurement once, it could have been caused by another program interrupting yours momentarily.

Comment: the company organizing the competition took the measurement, yes it is an average 0                                                     1)   Correct (100%)   0   
2)   Correct (100%)   0   
3)   Correct (100%)   0  
4)   Correct (100%)   0  
5)   Correct (100%)   0  
6)   Correct (100%)   0  
7)   Correct (100%)   0.004 
8)   Correct (100%)   0.012  
9)   Correct (100%)   0.012  
10)   Correct (100%)   0.012

Comment: I'd recommend timing it yourself. Timing code is a useful experience to have under your belt, and you and your peers can learn it together.  Not only that, but you can run the code X times, and make X however many you want.  I'd be willing to bet a 0,004 ms difference was caused by context switching.